# Symbolic simplification to least number of plus and multiply operations

Tags: python, matlab, symbolic-math

Recently I have to work with algorithms with a lot of long symbolic expressions such as this one

```
upperside = (    e * e * n * p * tn * tn + 
             2 * e * e * n * p * tn * tp +  
                 e * e * n * p * tp * tp + 
             2 * e * n * n * p * te * tn + 
             2 * e * n * n * p * te * tp +
                 N * e * n * n * tp * tp + 
             2 * e * n * p * p * te * tn +
             2 * e * n * p * p * te * tp - 
             2 * N * e * n * p * tn * tp + 
                 N * e * p * p * tn * tn +
                 n * n * n * p * te * te + 
             2 * n * n * p * p * te * te + 
                 n * p * p * p * te * te)
```

remformated

```
upperside = (        e * e * n         * p                  * tn * tn           + 
             2     * e * e * n         * p                  * tn      * tp      +  
                     e * e * n         * p                            * tp * tp + 
             2     * e     * n * n     * p         * te     * tn                + 
             2     * e     * n * n     * p         * te               * tp      +
                 N * e     * n * n                                    * tp * tp + 
             2     * e     * n         * p * p     * te     * tn                +
             2     * e     * n         * p * p     * te               * tp      - 
             2 * N * e     * n         * p                  * tn      * tp      + 
                 N * e                 * p * p              * tn * tn           +
                             n * n * n * p         * te * te                    + 
             2             * n * n     * p * p     * te * te                    + 
                             n         * p * p * p * te * te)
```

These expressions are derived from MATLAB symbolic routine after simplification. It is clear in this case, it is not possible to simplify the algebraic expression by, e.g., merging factors. However, it seems quite possible to simplify this expression so that the actual number of operations are greatly reduced. Unfortunately, I am not able to find such options in MATLAB or Python.

Any help is appreciated.

**EDIT**
The goal is to minimize the operations that CPU needs to perform for such expressions. Since the operations only involves addition and multiplication, I am hoping to something like (e+tn)*(te+tp)+n+.... I have tried to factor the expression but unfortunately the expressions are not factorizable.

Comment: So what will be the output ?

Comment: I am hoping a combination of product and addition (for example,  (e+n)(te+tp)+te+n...). The goal is to find a way to calculate the said quantities so that as few CPU operations are involved as possible

Comment: You removed the `Python` tag, but you still have mentioned `Python` in your question. Which one is a mistake or irrelevant?

Comment: in Python - Sympy? e.g. [this](http://live.sympy.org/?evaluate=e%2C%20p%2C%20n%2C%20N%2C%20tn%2C%20tp%2C%20te%20%3D%20symbols(%27e%20p%20n%20N%20tn%20tp%20te%27)%0A%23--%0Asimplify(e*e*n*p*tn*tn%2B2*e*e*n*p*tn*tp%2Be*e*n*p*tp*tp%2B2*e*n*n*p*te*tn%2B2*e*n*n*p*te*tp%2BN*e*n*n*tp*tp)%0A%23--%0A)

Comment: @Sardar_Usama I tried to move the tag so that symbolic math comes first. But for some reason I have blown it......

Comment: See `collect` and `simplify` in Matlab and their various options described in the documentation.

Comment: @horchler How do simplify work in this case? I cannot find an option that allows me to find the minimal number of operations.

Comment: That's not the goal of `simplify` or `collect`. If you have a strict criterion such as that you'll need to implement something like in the answer by @EricDuminil that checks every possible way of combining terms. Even that may not be the absolute minimum as simplification techniques cannot possibly be exhaustive in every case.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If any python package can help, it would probably be [Sympy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SymPy) :

```
from sympy import init_printing, symbols, simplify, collect, factor

e,n,p,tn,te,tp,N = symbols("e,n,p,tn,te,tp,N")

upperside = (e * e * n * p * tn * tn + 
         2 * e * e * n * p * tn * tp +
             e * e * n * p * tp * tp + 
         2 * e * n * n * p * te * tn + 
         2 * e * n * n * p * te * tp +
             N * e * n * n * tp * tp + 
         2 * e * n * p * p * te * tn +
         2 * e * n * p * p * te * tp - 
         2 * N * e * n * p * tn * tp + 
             N * e * p * p * tn * tn +
             n * n * n * p * te * te + 
         2 * n * n * p * p * te * te + 
             n * p * p * p * te * te)

print collect(upperside, e*n)
```

It outputs :

```
N*e*p**2*tn**2 + 
e**2*n*(p*tn**2 + 2*p*tn*tp + p*tp**2) + 
e*n**2*(N*tp**2 + 2*p*te*tn + 2*p*te*tp) + 
e*n*(-2*N*p*tn*tp + 2*p**2*te*tn + 2*p**2*te*tp) + 
n**3*p*te**2 + 
2*n**2*p**2*te**2 + 
n*p**3*te**2
```

Of all the methods described in this [page](http://docs.sympy.org/dev/tutorial/simplification.html), `collect` looks the most promising.

Here's a quick and dirty way to iterate over all the combinations of symbols and display the shortest expression found :

```
from sympy import init_printing, symbols, collect, pprint
import itertools

init_printing()

e,n,p,tn,te,tp,big_n = symbols("e,n,p,tn,te,tp,big_n")

upperside = (e * e * n * p * tn * tn + 2 * e * e * n * p * tn * tp +
                 e * e * n * p * tp * tp + 2 * e * n * n * p * te * tn + 2 * e * n * n * p * te * tp +
                 big_n * e * n * n * tp * tp + 2 * e * n * p * p * te * tn +
                 2 * e * n * p * p * te * tp - 2 * big_n * e * n * p * tn * tp + big_n * e * p * p * tn * tn +
                 n * n * n * p * te * te + 2 * n * n * p * p * te * te + n * p * p * p * te * te)

my_symbols = [e, n, p, tn, te, tp, big_n]

min_length = float('inf')

for i in range(len(my_symbols)):
  for symbol_subsets in itertools.combinations(my_symbols, i+1):
      collect_by = '*'.join(str(symbol) for symbol in symbol_subsets)
      expression = collect(upperside, collect_by)
      length = len(str(expression))
      if length < min_length:
          min_length = length
          print "With '%s' :" % collect_by
          pprint(expression)
          print
```

It outputs :

```
With 'e' :
e**2*(n*p*tn**2 + 2*n*p*tn*tp + n*p*tp**2) + e*(big_n*n**2*tp**2 - 2*big_n*n*p*tn*tp + big_n*p**2*tn**2 + 2*n**2*p*te*tn + 2*n**2*p*te*tp + 2*n*p**2*te*tn + 2*n*p**2*te*tp) + n**3*p*te**2 + 2*n**2*p**2*te**2 + n*p**3*te**2

With 'n' :
big_n*e*p**2*tn**2 + n**3*p*te**2 + n**2*(big_n*e*tp**2 + 2*e*p*te*tn + 2*e*p*te*tp + 2*p**2*te**2) + n*(-2*big_n*e*p*tn*tp + e**2*p*tn**2 + 2*e**2*p*tn*tp + e**2*p*tp**2 + 2*e*p**2*te*tn + 2*e*p**2*te*tp + p**3*te**2)

With 'e*n' :
big_n*e*p**2*tn**2 + e**2*n*(p*tn**2 + 2*p*tn*tp + p*tp**2) + e*n**2*(big_n*tp**2 + 2*p*te*tn + 2*p*te*tp) + e*n*(-2*big_n*p*tn*tp + 2*p**2*te*tn + 2*p**2*te*tp) + n**3*p*te**2 + 2*n**2*p**2*te**2 + n*p**3*te**2

With 'e*n*p' :
big_n*e*n**2*tp**2 - 2*big_n*e*n*p*tn*tp + big_n*e*p**2*tn**2 + e**2*n*p*(tn**2 + 2*tn*tp + tp**2) + e*n**2*p*(2*te*tn + 2*te*tp) + e*n*p**2*(2*te*tn + 2*te*tp) + n**3*p*te**2 + 2*n**2*p**2*te**2 + n*p**3*te**2
```

Answer (score 1):

Common subexpression elimination (or sympy cse) calculates products like: e*e and e*p and additions as well. This helps to find a really well optimized expression. I have seen a huge expression with 3 different mathematical approaches and the calculation time was vastly different. After using cse the 3 formulations were almost identical regarding calculation times. And some big factors faster, than the fastest non-optimized algorithm.